# Scala - Co-occurence matrix

Tags: scala, matrix

I am trying to make a co-occurence matrix from a txt file which a symmetric matrix.
I managed the first steps but now I am stuck.

For example if I had the text "I am making a post on stackoverflow and I am here"
I would have :

```
 List( (I,2), (am,2), (making,1), (a,1), (post,1), (on,1),(stackoverflow,1), (here,1) )
```

And then to create my matrix I need stgh like:

```
first line : List( ((I,I),2 or 4 idk) ((I,am),4), ((I,making),3), ((I, a),2) ... )
Second line: List( ((am,I),4), ((am,am),2 or 4), ... )
etc.
```

I need all key combinations with the sum of values but I can't find a proper solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume smth like following should solve your problem.

```
  val ll = List(("I", 2), ("am", 2), ("making", 1), ("a", 1), ("post", 1), ("on", 1), ("stackoverflow", 1), ("here", 1))

  val r = ll.map { x =>
    ll.map { y =>
      ((x._1, y._1), x._2 + y._2)
    }
  }
  r.foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
List(((I,I),4), ((I,am),4), ((I,making),3), ((I,a),3), ((I,post),3), ((I,on),3), ((I,stackoverflow),3), ((I,here),3))
List(((am,I),4), ((am,am),4), ((am,making),3), ((am,a),3), ((am,post),3), ((am,on),3), ((am,stackoverflow),3), ((am,here),3))
List(((making,I),3), ((making,am),3), ((making,making),2), ((making,a),2), ((making,post),2), ((making,on),2), ((making,stackoverflow),2), ((making,here),2))
List(((a,I),3), ((a,am),3), ((a,making),2), ((a,a),2), ((a,post),2), ((a,on),2), ((a,stackoverflow),2), ((a,here),2))
List(((post,I),3), ((post,am),3), ((post,making),2), ((post,a),2), ((post,post),2), ((post,on),2), ((post,stackoverflow),2), ((post,here),2))
List(((on,I),3), ((on,am),3), ((on,making),2), ((on,a),2), ((on,post),2), ((on,on),2), ((on,stackoverflow),2), ((on,here),2))
List(((stackoverflow,I),3), ((stackoverflow,am),3), ((stackoverflow,making),2), ((stackoverflow,a),2), ((stackoverflow,post),2), ((stackoverflow,on),2), ((stackoverflow,stackoverflow),2), ((stackoverflow,here),2))
List(((here,I),3), ((here,am),3), ((here,making),2), ((here,a),2), ((here,post),2), ((here,on),2), ((here,stackoverflow),2), ((here,here),2))
```

Comment: I tried the code above but there is an error when I type in
            r.foreach(println)

Maybe because ll is actually not a List but a type:

org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffleRDD[2] at reduceByKey at <console>:33
And r is of type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)]] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:36

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the question properly. Calling Words[n][2] your first Array of n words with their associated counts, then the m-th word would be Words[m-1,0] and its count Words[m-1,1]. Let's then define another Array WordCouples[n²][3], containing each possible couple of words and the sum of their respective counts. WordCouples has n² entries, each containing 3 values: WordCouples[i,0] contains the first word, WordCouples[i,1] contains the second word of the i-th combination, and WordCouples [i,2] contains the sum of the counts of the two words.

Then you can fill in WordCouples from Words, as follows:

```
for (int i; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j; j<n; j++) {
        WordCouples[n*i+j,0]=Word[i,0];
        WordCouples[n*i+j,1]=Word[j,0];
        WordCouples[n*i+j,2]=Word[i,1]+Word[j,1];
    }
```

Please note that the above is only mentioned as a suggested logical approach for your solution. Most likely you need to split the "String" from the "int" elements of the above arrays.